# Can't embed font in AS3, Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

I'm trying to embed my custom font in a Flash application but I get following error during compilation:

> C:\Users\trap\Downloads\flex_sdk_4.6\bin>mxmlc test.as
>
> C:\Users\trap\Downloads\flex_sdk_4.6\bin\test.as: Error: A file found in a source-path 'test' must have the same name as the class definition inside the file 'EmbededFonts'.

Here is my code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class EmbededFonts extends Sprite {

        [Embed(source = "dexter.ttf",
            fontName = "myFont",
            mimeType = "application/x-font",
            fontWeight = "normal",
            fontStyle = "normal",
            advancedAntiAliasing = "true",
            embedAsCFF = "false")]
        private var fontFontSample: Class;


        public function EmbededFonts() {
            super();

            var textFormat: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            textFormat.font = "myFont";
            textFormat.bold = true;
            textFormat.letterSpacing = 10;

            var textField: TextField = new TextField();
            textField.width = 300;
            textField.embedFonts = true
            textField.text = "Use embeded font";
            textField.textColor = 0x0000ff;
            textField.setTextFormat(textFormat);

            this.addChild(textField);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to rename your file to "EmbeddedFonts.as".  The compiler wants public class names to be stored in files using the class name itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what does the error message say in plain English?

> A file found in a source-path 'test' **must have the same name as the class** definition inside the file 'EmbededFonts'.

Let's have a look at your file name:

> C:\Users\trap\Downloads\flex_sdk_4.6\bin>mxmlc **test.as**

And what's the name of the class definition inside the file?

> public class **EmbededFonts** extends Sprite

They are clearly not the same, although they should be the same. Make them the same and you should not get that error any more.